# Restricting domain in ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

How would one restrict the domain on a `ParametricPlot`? For example, I have the following plot:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]; xi = 2; k0 = 9; \[Sigma] = 2; 
Show[Table[sol = NDSolve[{D[xtraj[t], t] == 
   -(Sinh[2 xtraj[t]/(Cosh2 xtraj[t])), xtraj[0] == n}, xtraj[t], {t, 0, 4}]; 
ParametricPlot[{xtraj[t], t} /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Full, Medium}, 
 AxesStyle -> Thickness[.003], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Medium}, 
 AxesLabel -> {xtraj, t}], {n, -4, 4 - 0.09, 0.09}]]
```

How can I exclude `-0.1 > xtraj[t] > 0.1`?

I simply can restrict the range but not the domain?

Comment: I thought using a well-known name I may get an answer - changed it to my name now.

Comment: does this give what you need: `ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate[ConditionalExpression[{xtraj[t], t}, 
    Not[-.1 <= xtraj[t] <= .1]] /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 4}, ...]`?

Comment: .. or `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{xtraj[t], t} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 4}, 
 RegionFunction -> (Not[-.1 <= # <= .2] &), ...]`?

Comment: No it does not :-(

Comment: Using the following works: RegionFunction -> (Not[-.1 <= #1 <= .2] &)

Comment: Thank this short bit of code works.

Answer (score 1):

Add the option

```
RegionFunction -> (Not[-.1 <= # <= .2] &)
```

to your `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Thanks that works.

Comment: @Betty, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.